# using transform on an object from array always returns 0,0,0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some odd reason the script i wrote always returns 0,0,0 for positions of other objects from an array.

(Note: This script takes the average of distances to other objects and averages them, which is used to move the host object)

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompleteGravityModel : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector2 InitialVelocity;

    public long Mass;

    public float TimeMultiplier;

    Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
          rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
    GameObject[] Planets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Planet"); // Gets everything marked as "Planet"
    
    GameObject[] Stars = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sun"); // The same operation, but with stars.

    Vector3[] PlanetDists = new Vector3[Planets.Length];

    Vector3[] StarDists = new Vector3[Stars.Length];

    Vector3 SummedPlanetVector = new Vector3();

    Vector3 SummedStarVector = new Vector3();

    Vector3 Velocity = new Vector3();


    for (long PlanetsChecked = 0; Planets.Length==PlanetsChecked ; PlanetsChecked++){ 
        if (!(Planets[PlanetsChecked].transform == transform)){ // If it is the host, don't add.
            PlanetDists[PlanetsChecked] = transform.position-Planets[PlanetsChecked].transform.position; // Gets distances from the host to the planet
        }
    }

    for (long StarsChecked = 0; Stars.Length==StarsChecked; StarsChecked++){ 
        if (!(Stars[StarsChecked].transform == transform)){ // If it is the host, don't add.
            StarDists[StarsChecked] = transform.position-Stars[StarsChecked].transform.position; // Gets distances from the host to the star
        }
    }


    for (long PDVectorsChecked = 0; PDVectorsChecked==PlanetDists.Length; PDVectorsChecked++){ // Sums up the planet distances into a one large vector.
        SummedPlanetVector += PlanetDists[PDVectorsChecked];
    }

    for (long SDVectorsChecked = 0; SDVectorsChecked==StarDists.Length; SDVectorsChecked++){ // Sums up the star distances into a one large vector.
        SummedStarVector += StarDists[SDVectorsChecked];
    }


    Velocity = (SummedPlanetVector+SummedStarVector)/(StarDists.Length+PlanetDists.Length); // the final velocity for this object to move.
    rb.velocity += (Velocity*Time.deltaTime*TimeMultiplier)/Mass;
    Debug.Log(Velocity);
    }
}
```

Nothing. I am just confused by this problem.

Comment: time to add debugging.